# UNZIP failed while extracting

Tags: zip

```
%> unzip V15679-01_3of3.zip
Archive:  V15679-01_3of3.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of V15679-01_3of3.zip or
        V15679-01_3of3.zip.zip, and cannot find V15679-01_3of3.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Downloaded zip file and tried but it gave the above error.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the archive is incomplete because it has been interrupted whilst being downloaded or it was not compressed correctly by the person who originally created it. It might also be part of a set of compressed archives so you will need the full set to uncompress them i.e.

```
$ unzip archive1.zip archive2.zip archive3.zip
```

I would try sourcing the archive again. You might also look at the man page for flags that give more output when the unzip operation fails, `-t` `-v`.

Comment: unzip V15679-01_1of3.zip V15679-01_2of3.zip V15679-01_3of3.zip
Archive:  V15679-01_1of3.zip
caution: filename not matched:  V15679-01_2of3.zip
caution: filename not matched:  V15679-01_3of3.zip